# Importing AzureMobileServices framework and Bridging-Header

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, azure, bridging-header

I've tried a million different ways to import the AzureMobileServices framework into XCode but Im still getting an error.
So I followed the guide Microsoft provides, which is pretty straight forward:

- Donwload SDK and add the file to a new group (frameworks) inside your project.
- Create the bridging header: projectName-Bridging-Header and add the following import:

  `#import <WindowsAzureMobileServices/WindowsAzureMobileServices.h>`

I dont get any error message but I cant use the actual library since something in the import is done wrong. I've check multiple times the swift compiler line I added is right and that I didnt miss spelled anything on the imports.

Thank you in advanced! :)